# Lift of inclusion $U(k)$ into $SO(2k)$ to $Spin^c$ group

Tags: lie-groups, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

In "Clifford Modules" by Atiyah, Bott and Shapiro (p.10) or "Dirac Operators in Riemannian Geometry" by Friedrich (p.28) one finds some sort of a lift of the natural inclusion $\operatorname{U}(k)\to \operatorname{SO}(2k)$ to the group $\mathrm{Spin^c}(2k)$.

So if $f_{\mathit{can}}:\operatorname{U}(k)\to \operatorname{SO}(2k)\times S^1:A\mapsto (A,\det A)$ is given, they state the following  $F_{\mathit{can}}:\operatorname{U}(k)\to \operatorname{Spin}^c(2k)=\operatorname{Spin}(2k)\times_{\mathbb{Z}_2}S^1$ is a lift.

$
A\mapsto F_{\mathit{can}}(A):= \prod_{j=1}^k\big(\cos \frac{\theta_j}{2} +\sin \frac{\theta_j}{2} \cdot \cdot u_j\cdot J(u_j)\big)\times e^{\frac{i}{2}\sum_{j=1}^k \theta_j },
$

where $J$ is the complex structure as a map $\mathbb{C}^k\to \mathbb{C}^k$, and $(u_1,J(u_k),\ldots, u_k,J(u_k))$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2k}$, some of the dots are Clifford multiplication and the "angles" $\theta_j$ come from writing $A$ as a matrix
$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
e^{i \theta_1} &&\\
& \ddots &\\
& & e^{i \theta_k}
\end{bmatrix}$.

It is never explicitely shown why this is a group homomorphism. So I tried to do it. Let $B$ be another matrix  representing an element $\operatorname{U}(k)$ with angles $\zeta_j$.

\begin{align*}
&\big(\cos \frac{\theta_j}{2} +\sin \frac{\theta_j}{2}\cdot u_j\cdot J(u_j)   \big)\cdot \big(\cos \frac{\zeta_j}{2} +\sin \frac{\zeta_j}{2}  \cdot u_j\cdot J(u_j) \big)\\
\quad & = \cos \frac{\theta_j}{2}\cos \frac{\zeta_j}{2}+\sin \frac{\theta_j}{2} \cos \frac{\zeta_j}{2}\cdot u_j\cdot J(u_j)\\
\quad&\phantom{=}+\cos \frac{\theta_j}{2} \sin \frac{\zeta_j}{2} u_j\cdot J(u_j)+ \sin \frac{\theta_j}{2} \sin \frac{\zeta_j}{2}\cdot \underbrace{u_j\cdot J(u_j)\cdot u_j\cdot J(u_j)}_{=-1 \text{ by Clifford mult. law.}}\\
\quad & =\cos \frac{\theta_j+\zeta_j}{2}+\sin \frac{\theta_j+\zeta_j}{2}\cdot u_j\cdot J(u_j)
\end{align*}
If this is right I do not get why one needs the second factor with the determinant. Asked differently: What is wrong here and how does one do it right?

Comment: I think I found a solution, will post it soon.

Comment: What order is the product $\prod_{j=1}^k$ in? Also, your computation seemed to only check with one factor, so in other words you seem to only be checking $k=1$. When $k>1$, the complex matrices $A$ and $B$ may be diagonal with respect to *different* bases, so you'd have $u_j$s and $v_j$s without much relation with each other.